# how to add string depth when already deep in syntax

Tags: php, html

Php code:

```
 <?php echo '<h1 class="woning'.$counter.' woningen"onClick="javascript:changeText(this);$("#projects woningproject"'.$counter.'").slideToggle(300)">>' .$row->Projecttitel. '</h1>'; ?>
```

This will generate

```
<h1 class="woning1 woningen" woningproject"1"").slidetoggle(300)"="" #projects="" onclick="javascript:changeText(this);$(">>Wijveld</h1>
```

Why ? 
Because the first " before #projects closes the onChange tag..
I have no idea how to fix my " & 's to do this, as i seemingly need to use something that is a level deeper than that.

Comment: What is in `$counter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo '<h1 class="woning'.$counter.' woningen" onClick="javascript: changeText(this); $(\'#projects woningproject'.$counter.'\').slideToggle(300)">' .$row->Projecttitel. '</h1>'; ?>
```

You just need to escape the nested quotes for it to work.

Comment: Generated HTML is:
<h1 class="woning1 woningen" woningproject1\").slidetoggle(300)"="" #projects="" onclick="javascript: changeText(this); $(\">Wijveld</h1>

Comment: <h1 class="woning1 woningen" onclick="javascript: changeText(this); $('#projects woningproject1').slideToggle(300)">Wijveld</h1>
<div class="projects woningproject1">

Can't see why this ain't working

Comment: do you have jquery included ? Also, if you are using jquery, just use the dom ready handler. that is much cleaner.? One more thing, look  for console log errors

Comment: Yes; i fixed it, it was a class and thus.  $(\'.woningproject'

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$counter = 123;

$row = new stdClass();
$row->Projecttitel = 'SampleProjecttite';

// Here onwards
$class = sprintf('woning%s woningen', $counter);
$click = sprintf('javascript:changeText(this); $(\'#projects woningproject%s\').slideToggle(300)', $counter);

echo sprintf('<h1 class="%s" onclick="%s">%s</h1>', $class, $click, $row->Projecttitel);
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
<?php echo '<h1 class="woning'.$counter.' woningen" onClick="javascript:changeText(this);$(\'#projects .woningproject'.$counter.'\').slideToggle(300)">' .$row->Projecttitel. '</h1>'; ?>
```

Notice dot in front of "woningproject" class because w/o dot you targeting tag instead class.